# How can I pull older branches of a package from github using go get command

Tags: go, github, glide-golang

From this link:

> https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/tree/v1.4

I want to get this module.
How can I do it? I don't want to get `master` module, but I want to get `v1.4` branch. When I use the following command, it downloads `master` module:

> go get github.com/googollee/go-socket.io

How can I use `go get` for an older version or other branches?

Comment: If you're using Go modules (added in v1.11), you can just use `go get github.com/googollee/go-socket.io@v1.4.0` (or whatever 1.4.x version you want).

Comment: @Adrian , My dear go get github.com/googollee/go-socket.io@v1.4.0 dont work

Comment: @Adrian go: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode

Comment: Correct - that's why I started off saying "If you're using Go modules". If you are using a recent version of Go, you might consider updating your project to use modules, it makes it much easier to manage dependencies like this where you want a specific version.

Comment: @Adrian how can i use Go modules ?

Comment: @Adrian , i want to install v1.0 , v1.4 and.... my go veriosn : go version go1.12.9 windows/amd64

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: @Adrian can you connect my pc with teamviewer and solve my problem?

Comment: i use this https://github.com/zhouhui8915/socket.io-go and run go get github.com/googollee/go-socket.io

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

You need to use modules. Module-based behavior is an opt-in feature that is available from **Go 1.11** but it is disabled by default in `%GOPATH%` directory. (If you don't know your `%GOPATH%`, run `go env`.) For example, if your `%GOPATH%` is set to `C:\Users\Melina\go` (I suppose so in the remainder of the answer), you cannot use module-based behavior of `go get` in that directory or its subdirectories like`C:\Users\Melina\go\src` regarding default settings. To change it, do the following steps:

1. Set `GO111MODULE` environment variable to `on`

   Add an environment variable called `GO111MODULE` and set it to `on`. (You can do this simply by running command `setx GO111MODULE "on"` in Windows shell either Command Prompt or Windows Powershell. You **MUST** repoen the shell so it takes effect. Or if you are using Visual Studio Code, restart your IDE.)
2. In `C:\Users\Melina\go\src`, create a directory called e.g. `socket.io.1.4`. It will contain source code of `socket.io` module. Run the following commands:
3. `cd C:\Users\Melina\go\socket.io.1.4`
4. `go mod init github.com/googollee/go-socket.io@v1.4` to create a module that pulls `v1.4` of `go-socket.io`.
5. `go get github.com/googollee/go-socket.io@v1.4` to get the specified version of the module. Getting the module will start like this:
   [image]

There is an alternative way without touching `GO111MODULE`. Since out of `%GOPATH%`, the module-based behavior is enabled by default, you can do step 2 out of `%GOPATH%`, i.e. create directory `socket.io.1.4` out of `C:\Users\Melina\go` and its subdirectories. Other steps are the same.

Comment: can you tell me how can install v.1.0 ? can you type me ? learn me with exaple

Comment: @melina disregard this answer, it's totally irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Dear , how can use old version of this link? https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/